# Voronoi from delaunay triangulation

Tags: 2d, computational-geometry, voronoi, delaunay

I have almost finished my Delaunay / Voronoi triangulator and it was hard.
I haven't used the Fortun's code, I created the Delaunay triangulator and I derive the Voronoi diagram from that.

There is a problem though; infinite lines.  I cannot find a method to define the Voronoi cells delimited by those infinite lines, I have tried almost anything.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I derive a Voronoi diagram given its point set and its Delaunay triangulation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85275/how-do-i-derive-a-voronoi-diagram-given-its-point-set-and-its-delaunay-triangula)

Answer (score 4):

To fix the infinite lines, just add an extra vertex at infinity where they all meet.  From here, you just do the usual dual map, taking faces <-> verts.  That's it.